# php: free packetsniffer for debugging

Tags: php, debugging, uploadify

i'm looking for a free and lightweight packetsniffer for debugging internal server errors like 500. i am using uploadify for uploading files, unfortunately there's no comfortable way to log internal errors.
is there any good freeware tool for this?

Comment: The webservers `error.log` already documents internal errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to take a look at http://www.wireshark.org/

Also, the Firefox Live HTTP Headers extension can be helpful in identifying issues on the http request/response cycle, without having you to take into account lower protocol layers.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a standalone class to make uploaded files easier to use.

See https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Form/UploadedFile.php

As you can see from the source code, you can get any of the errors from UploadedFile::hasErrors() or UploadedFile::getErrorMessage()

The https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/IncomingHttpRequest.php class may also be of help to you.

Hope that helps...